# Highlight a selected item in React-Native FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I put together a simple React-native application to gets data from a remote service, loads it in a FlatList. When a user taps on an item, it should be highlighted and selection should be retained. I am sure such a trivial operation should not be difficult. I am not sure what I am missing.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

export default class BasicFlatList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      page: 1,
      seed: 1,
      error: null,
      refreshing: false,
      selectedItem:'null',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }

  makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const {page, seed} = this.state;
    const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=20`;
    this.setState({loading: true});
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: page === 1 ? res.results : [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({error, loading: false});
      });
  };

  onPressAction = (rowItem) => {
    console.log('ListItem was selected');
    console.dir(rowItem);
    this.setState({
      selectedItem: rowItem.id.value
    });
  }

  renderRow = (item) => {
    const isSelectedUser = this.state.selectedItem === item.id.value;
    console.log(`Rendered item - ${item.id.value} for ${isSelectedUser}`);
    const viewStyle = isSelectedUser ? styles.selectedButton : styles.normalButton;
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity style={viewStyle} onPress={() => this.onPressAction(item)} underlayColor='#dddddd'>
          <View style={styles.listItemContainer}>
            <View>
              <Image source={{ uri: item.picture.large}} style={styles.photo} />
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start',}}>
                {isSelectedUser ?
                  <Text style={styles.selectedText}>{item.name.first} {item.name.last}</Text>
                  : <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name.first} {item.name.last}</Text>
                }
              </View>
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start',}}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.email}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <FlatList style={styles.container}
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          this.renderRow(item)
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  selectedButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
  },
  normalButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  listItemContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 12,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  text: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  selectedText: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  photo: {
    height: 40,
    width: 40,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
});
```

When user taps on an item in the list, "onPress" method is invoked with the information on selected item. But the next step of highlight item in Flatlist does not happen. 'UnderlayColor' is of no help either.

Any help/advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: You will also need to modify your data (state), in your `onPressAction` func replace `setState` with `this.setState({selectedItem: rowItem.id.value, data: {...this.state.data}});` But this is not recommended way.

Comment: I tried that. Did not help

Comment: @KrishnanSriram i have the same problem. is the answer you chose below working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In place of `this.state.selectedItem` and setting with/checking for a `rowItem.id.value`, I would recommend using a Map object with key:value pairs as shown in the RN FlatList docs example: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html. Take a look at the js Map docs as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map.

The extraData prop recommended by @j.I-V will ensure re-rendering occurs when this.state.selected changes on selection.

Your onPressAction will obviously change a bit from example below depending on if you want to limit the number of selections at any given time or not allow user to toggle selection, etc.

Additionally, though not necessary by any means, I like to use another class or pure component for the `renderItem` component; ends up looking something like the following:

```js
export default class BasicFlatList extends Component {
  state = {
    otherStateStuff: ...,
    selected: (new Map(): Map<string, boolean>) //iterable object with string:boolean key:value pairs
  }

  onPressAction = (key: string) => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      //create new Map object, maintaining state immutability
      const selected = new Map(state.selected);
      //remove key if selected, add key if not selected
      this.state.selected.has(key) ? selected.delete(key) : selected.set(key, !selected.get(key));
      return {selected};
    });
  }

  renderRow = (item) => {
    return (
        <RowItem
          {...otherProps}
          item={item}
          onPressItem={this.onPressAction}
          selected={!!this.state.selected.get(item.key)} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <FlatList style={styles.container}
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          this.renderRow(item)
        )}
        extraData={this.state}
      />
    );
  }
}


class RowItem extends Component {
  render(){
    //render styles and components conditionally using this.props.selected ? _ : _
    
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPressItem}>
        ...
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why delete has 2 arguments?

Comment: @KailashUniyal Good find! That delete method should only take one argument (a key), so I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 19):

You can do something like:

1. For the `renderItem`, use something like a `TouchableOpacity` with an `onPress` event passing the index or id of the `renderedItem`;
2. Function to add the selected item to a state:

```js
handleSelection = (id) => {
   var selectedId = this.state.selectedId

   if(selectedId === id)
     this.setState({selectedItem: null})
   else
     this.setState({selectedItem: id})
}

handleSelectionMultiple = (id) => {
   var selectedIds = [...this.state.selectedIds] // clone state

   if(selectedIds.includes(id))
     selectedIds = selectedIds.filter(_id => _id !== id)
   else
     selectedIds.push(id)

   this.setState({selectedIds})
}
```

3. `FlatList`:

```js
<FlatList
  data={data}
  extraData={
    this.state.selectedId     // for single item
    this.state.selectedIds    // for multiple items
  }
  renderItem={(item) =>
     <TouchableOpacity

       // for single item
       onPress={() => this.handleSelection(item.id)}
       style={item.id === this.state.selectedId ? styles.selected : null}

       // for multiple items
       onPress={() => this.handleSelectionMultiple(item.id)}
       style={this.state.selectedIds.includes(item.id) ? styles.selected : null}
     >
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
  }
/>
```

4. Make a style for the selected item and that's it!

Comment: How can i do it for multiple items ?

Comment: @Ranjit A little late but I edited my answer to both cases

Comment: how can i limit user selection to only two items?

Comment: @gSaenz You can do something like on handleSelectionMultiple function:  if (selectedIds.length > 2) return

Comment: This is turning all items in my flatlist to the "Selected" style. Any idea what the fix is?

Comment: @kalculated Did you check the this.state.selectedIds values?

Comment: @MaiconGilton hey! I realized I was comparing the wrong id with selectedId. Got it working, upvoted!

Answer (score 7):

You should pass an `extraData` prop to your `FlatList` so that it will re-render your items based on your selection.

Here:

```js
    <FlatList style={styles.container}
        data={this.state.data}
        extraData={this.state.selectedItem}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          this.renderRow(item)
        )}
     />
```

Source : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

> Make sure that everything your `renderItem` function depends on is passed as a `prop` (e.g. `extraData`) that is not `===` after updates, otherwise your UI may not update on changes.

Answer (score 0):

First

```js
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedIds:[]
    };
  }
```

Second:

```js
handleSelectionMultiple = async (id) => {
var selectedIds = [...this.state.selectedIds] // clone state
if(selectedIds.includes(id))
  selectedIds = selectedIds.filter(_id => _id !== id)
else
  selectedIds.push(id)
await this.setState({selectedIds})
}
```

Third

```js
<CheckBox
     checked={this.state.selectedIds.includes(item.expense_detail_id) ? true : false}
     onPress={()=>this.handleSelectionMultiple(item.expense_detail_id)}
 />
```

Finally I got the solution to my problem from the answer given by Maicon Gilton.