# How to animate a single item from Flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a array of data which I render in flatlist in React-Native. On pressing one of the items I want it to fade away, but instead all items on the flatlist get animated and not just the one that I pressed on.

```
constructor(props){ 
super(props); 
this.state = { fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1) }



  onPressButtonnotdelivered(item) {
    //Alert.alert(item.name)
      const animations = [
        Animated.timing(this.state.fadeAnim, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 500
        }),

      ];

      Animated.sequence(animations).start()
  }


  render() {
return (
  <View>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      extraData={this.state}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        return (
          <Animated.View key={index} style={[styles.animatedview, {opacity: this.state.fadeAnim}]}>
    <View>
    <View style={[styles.button, {backgroundColor: '#E94F64'}]}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonview}
    onPress={() => {this.onPressButtonnotdelivered(item)}}>
  <View style={styles.btnIcon}>
  <Icon name="block" size={30} />
    <Text>Not delivered</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
          </View>
          </Animated.View>
        );
      }}
    />
  </View>
);
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686365/highlight-a-selected-item-in-react-native-flatlist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add one more state to your component say `indexToAnimate` and set it to `null`.

Then put one condition in style of `<Animated.View>`

```
<Animated.View
        key={index}
        style={[
          styles.animatedview,
          {
            opacity:
              index == this.state.indexToAnimate
                ? this.state.fadeAnim
                : "whatever your static value is..(in integer)"
          }
        ]}
/>
```

and set `indexToAnimate` state on `onPress` method of `<TouchableOpacity>`

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.buttonview}
  onPress={() => {
    this.setState({ indexToAnimate: index }, () => this.onPressButtonnotdelivered(item));
  }}
>
  <View style={styles.btnIcon}>
    <Icon name="block" size={30} />
    <Text>Not delivered</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this almost solves my problem. Now when I click on the button just the one view fades out, but when I click on another button from another view, the previous pressed view shows up again and the newly pressed view fades ou,. What I need is that when the button is pressed it fades out and never shows up again, any thoughts?

Comment: That's because you haven't deleted your item from the state that you are passing to flatlist. Delete that item when you click on view.

Comment: Thanks dude, I used:  `let data = this.state.data.filter(cust => cust.id !== item.id)
      this.setState({data: data})`  to delete the view after the animations ends!

Answer (score 1):

What if you add a conditional render to the renderItem like:

```
renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
    if (index === 'id') 
      return(<Animated.View> ... </Animated.View>);
    else
      return(<View> ... </View>);
 }
```

Comment: Not sure if I was clear enough with my question. I need all view blocks to be animated, but when I click on a button I want that only view block to fadeout and when I click on another button, that other view should fadeout too. Right now all view blocks are fading out all at once no matter which view block button I click on

Comment: maybe this is a good starting point. https://medium.com/appdafuer/how-to-create-a-simple-swipeable-list-in-react-native-81b894ea5c4c it is a tutorial do implement a swipe to delete. you would have to change the swipe into a touch and tweak the delete animation a littlebit

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it